# add variable number of rows to a datatable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable that I am trying to add rows to, according to 2 user inputs which control the number of the rows and number of elements in each row.I am trying to do this with a nested for loop but I am stuck.

```
DataTable data = new DataTable("Data Example");

data.Columns.Add("Data");
for (int i =0 ; i < numOfAttrColumns ; i++)
{
    data.Columns.Add("Attr" + i);
}
data.Columns.Add("Result");

for (int i = 0; i < numOfExamples; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfAttrColumns+1; j++)
    {
        data.Rows.Add(.....)
    }
}
```

each row looks like this:

```
data.Rows.Add("D" + i, Example_Attr_Res[i],Example_Attr_Res [i+numOfExamples], Example_Attr_Res[i + 2*numOfExamples]... Example_Attr_Res[i + numOfAttrColumns * numOfExamples]);
```

as an example:

```
//if numOfExamples ==3 and numOfAttrColumns=4 and a=Example_Attr_Res;
data.Rows.Add("D0", a0, a3, a6, a9, a12);
data.Rows.Add("D1", a1, a4, a7, a10, a13);
data.Rows.Add("D2", a2, a5, a8, a11, a14);
```

Comment: You need to move the call to Add a row outside the inner loop. You add a row only after you have fully formed its column inside the inner loop. Use an object array to prepare the row elements

Comment: thats what you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you it solved the problem